# Regroup clusters generated by sklearn AgglomerativeClustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

After having generated a dendogram to see how many clusters to generate from my data, I decided to create 9 clusters using the following code :

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=9, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
cluster.fit_predict(data.values)
```

Here's the dendogram that was generated. Is there a simple way to group each of the 9 clusters in the bigger clusters that they belong to, or should I just rerun the clustering algorithm with less clusters each time and deduce which clusters are most similar ?

[image]